# Does sphere's movement get affected if the frictionless surface below it rotates?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, angular-momentum, reference-frames, friction, coriolis-effect

If a sphere has a constant velocity going in a straight line on a frictionless surface that rotates, from an inertial frame of reference, does the ball continue to travel in the same direction and speed, does the rotation of the surface cause any acceleration to the ball?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your question, the sphere moves on a frictionless surface. If so, it must make a linear motion. It is not subjected to perform rolling motion. There must be a torque to roll. In such a case, the torque is provided by friction. But as there is no friction here, it slips.

Now your question is what happens to the sphere if the surface starts to rotate. You told that you are observing from a non-inertial frame so you should be standing out of that surface.  When you look at the sphere like that, you can see no change in the motion of the sphere.

Why? In order for the motion of the sphere to change, an external force must act on it. Here you have applied a force to the surface. How can this force be transmitted from the surface to the sphere? The only way it can happen is through friction between the sphere and the surface. But because there is no friction here, no force is transmitted. Thus the motion of the sphere does not change.